# why I used layoutinflater in android?

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner developer in Android:

Could you explain what `layoutinflater` does and can you explain what it is used for in general and especially in this code?

I have this code :

```
 private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

    *** LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        int resId = 0;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            resId = R.layout.farleft;
            break;
        case 1:
            resId = R.layout.left;
            break;
        case 2:
            resId = R.layout.middle;
            break;
        case 3:
            resId = R.layout.right;
            break;
        case 4:
            resId = R.layout.farright;
            break;
        }

        View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: `explain why I used in general and spacial in this code?` Funny that we should explain you why you used it... also the documentation is pretty short and easy to understand. Have you even tried to read it?

Comment: i don't write that , i get that code from: mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/ . but i not understand why used layoutinflater in code .

Comment: If you haven't written it, don't say "why I used ...". Providing some context like you have just now should have been done in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LayoutInflater service converts a stored copy of your XML layout into a collection of real instantiated views in the application process memory space.

- The layout you created in your editor is saved as XML.
- The XML is embedded into your app as a resource.
- The layoutinflater reads the resource file.
- It then creates the views you have specified as objects.
- You can now manipulate the view objects from your code.

The Activity class does this process for you auto-magically when you call [setContentView(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

A `LayoutInflater` 'converts' an XML file to a `View` object, containing all the `View` children specified in that XML. You could also say that the 'flat' XML file is 'inflated' to a `View`.

See also [LayoutInflater | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)